# AJAX XHR request onReadyStateChange events order and number of times clarification

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm learning and trying to write a simple stock quote tool using Python-Flask and Javascript.

I specifically want to learn **plain** Javascript. My code is working, but what I don't understand is when I'm watching the developer console, I get 3 error messages printed before I get the successful console.log(response).

Is it simply that the code loops 3 times before the response comes back, so it logged 'ERROR' each of those times before finally returning the 200 status? Would someone explain it to me or point me to a good article/post?

My event listener:

```
document.getElementById("btn_quote").addEventListener("click", getQuote);
```

The ajax call:

```
function getQuote(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ticker = document.getElementById("ticker").value
    var shares = document.getElementById("shares").value
    var url = "/quote/"+ticker+"/"+shares

    // Fetch the latest data.
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(request.response);
                console.log(response);
            }
        } else {
            // TODO, handle error when no data is available.
            console.log('ERROR');
            return false;
        }
    };
        request.open('GET', url);
        request.send();
}
```

Comment: what error does it throw?

Comment: It's not throwing a real error. It's hitting the part of the code where I've asked it to log to the console so I could understand what's happening `console.log('ERROR');`

Comment: The issue is, you hit DONE once ... if the status is 200 all good, if it isn't, then you do nothing ... your `else` code is misplaced, that's the only issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, ajax calls will get notified for the following events which is called as `readyStateChange` event.

[image]

For most cases, you used to get 4 ready state changes based on the speed of the connection (rare cases only only one if it's very quick) and you should check whether it is **4** which means the response is completed now.

To check whether the request is suceess or not, you should check the `request.status === 200` which means success and can check for other `http status code` for errors like `404`, `500` etc.

```js
document.getElementById("btn_quote").addEventListener("click", getQuote);
document.getElementById("btn_quote_error").addEventListener("click", getQuoteError);

function getQuote(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ticker = document.getElementById("ticker").value;
    var shares = document.getElementById("shares").value;
    //var url = "/quote/" + ticker + "/" + shares;
    var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';

    // Fetch the latest data.
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      console.log(request.readyState);
        if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            console.log(request.status);
            if (request.status === 200) {
                //var response = JSON.parse(request.response);
                //console.log(response);
            }
        } 
        //else {
            // TODO, handle error when no data is available.
            //console.log('ERROR');
            //return false;
        //}
    };
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send();

  
}

function getQuoteError(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ticker = document.getElementById("ticker").value;
    var shares = document.getElementById("shares").value;
    //var url = "/quote/" + ticker + "/" + shares;
    var url = 'http://stackoverflow404.com/';

    // Fetch the latest data.
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      console.log(request.readyState);
        if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            console.log(request.status);
            if (request.status === 200) {
                //var response = JSON.parse(request.response);
                //console.log(response);
            }
        } 
        //else {
            // TODO, handle error when no data is available.
            //console.log('ERROR');
            //return false;
        //}
    };
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send();

  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ticker"/>
<input type="text" id="shares"/>
<input type="button" id="btn_quote" value="Get Quote" />
<input type="button" id="btn_quote_error" value="Get Quote Error" />
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not returning separate HTTP status codes, its returning different ready states.

Change your `console.log("ERROR");`. To `console.log(request.readyState);`.

Then you will see what it is reporting and why.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

i think you should be checking your `readyState` values with the actual values of the response. For you reference, following are the possible values of `readyState`:

```
0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established
2: request received 
3: processing request 
4: request finished and response is ready
```

So you could basically check it to be 4 in your case:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            //response statements
        } else {
            //error statements
        }
    };
```

Comment: glad that it helped you :)

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest.UNSENT === 0`, `XMLHttpRequest.OPENED === 1`, `XMLHttpRequest.HEADERS_RECEIVED ===2`, `XMLHttpRequest.LOADING === 3`, `XMLHttpRequest.DONE === 4` - so I can't see how this answers the question to be honest

Comment: Some browsers don't understand the XMLHttpRequest.DONE properties and hence, the answer